# How to get Unity back after switching to Gnome in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

I have a problem with Unity desktop. It was working fine until I switched and use Gnome for about 30 minutes. When I switched back to Unity, all I can see is the wallpaper and nothing else, no launcher and panel. I know its still working because when I right click, it shows the menu and I can even access the System setting via the change background option and the terminal via shortcut key. I believe its running fine its just that I can't do anything else because I can't see it on the desktop. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following command in a terminal (Ctrl Alt & T will open a terminal).

```
unity --reset
```